# mapping array in specific interval / range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why won't mapping change the array with this function:

```
array[1..5].map! { |part| "<p>#{part}</p>" }
```

I know that I could just assign array[1..5] to the result, but there's probably some better way to do it.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

> #### [](*args)
>
> Returns a new array populated with the given objects.
>
> [Source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D)

So, you're actually applying `map!` to a new array of just that range, not the actual array.

Assignment is necessary.

Comment: To assign back: `array[1,5] = array[1..5].map { ... }` If you're feeling adventuresome you could wrap this up into a method called something like `remap` and add it as a method to Array.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it *does* change the array. You're just not seeing it, because you never assign the array to anything, so it will be immediately garbage collected again.